# How to get the value of hidden in li with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I store filename in the value of hidden input, I hope to get the filename when I click Download or Rename label.
Such as I get file1 when I click the first element Download of li, how can I do ? Thanks!

```
function Download() {
  alert("filename I clicked");
}
```

**Html**

```
   <ul>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file1" /> <span onclick="Download()">Download</span>   <span onclick="Rename()">Rename</span> </li>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file2" /> <span onclick="Download()">Download</span>   <span onclick="Rename()">Rename</span> </li>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file3" /> <span onclick="Download()">Download</span>   <span onclick="Rename()">Rename</span> </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jquery` and `closest` to make it `generic` for both `download` and `rename` as below.

Also, you can get rid of the `function Download` in a `jquery` way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.download, span.rename').on('click', function() {
    var span = $(this);
    var fileName = span.closest('li').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
 
    if(span.is('.download')) {
       // download part
      alert('Download: ' + fileName);
    } else if(span.is('.rename')) {
       // rename part
      alert('Rename: ' + fileName);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.download, .rename {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file1" /> <span class="download">Download</span>   <span class="rename">Rename</span> </li>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file2" /> <span class="download">Download</span>   <span class="rename">Rename</span> </li>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file3" /> <span class="download">Download</span>   <span class="rename">Rename</span> </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Also, you might want to split those into two handlers, or show the op how to tell which type of element was clicked since they should trigger different actions;)

Comment: `$(this)` used here to evaluate `closest('li')` and `find('input[type="hidden"]')`

Comment: @DelightedD0D You are right, I have updated the code with `if(span.is('.link')) {`

Comment: What Im saying is that `var span = $(this);` is only needed if you are using `span` more than once, which you dont. `var fileName = $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();` is more appropriate here IMHO. It's not wrong, just superfluous.

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes, you are right. With `if(span.is('.download')) {`, now `span` is used more than once. Thanks for pointing out :-)

Comment: oh no, you misunderstand, the current +1 was from me the whole time :) I was just pointing out a way to make it even better :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D Ah okay, sorry for that and thanks for the +1 and the comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

Making some minor modifications to your HTML, you can use jQuery's `siblings` selector to get the corresponding `input` element, and from there get the value:

```js
function Download(el) {
  alert($(el).siblings("input").val());
}

var Rename = Download;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="file1" /> <span onclick="Download(this)">Download</span>  <span onclick="Rename(this)">Rename</span> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="file2" /> <span onclick="Download(this)">Download</span>  <span onclick="Rename(this)">Rename</span> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="file3" /> <span onclick="Download(this)">Download</span>  <span onclick="Rename(this)">Rename</span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the value of the previous element using jquery's prev() as shown below

```js
function Download(element) {
 var gettry=$(element).prev().val();
}
function Rename(element){
var gettry=$(element).prev().prev().val();
  console.log("getting "+gettry)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file1" /> <span onclick="Download(this)">Download</span>   <span onclick="Rename(this)">Rename</span> </li>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file2" /> <span onclick="Download(this)">Download</span>   <span onclick="Rename(this)">Rename</span> </li>
       <li >  <input type="hidden" value="file3" /> <span onclick="Download(this)">Download</span>   <span onclick="Rename(this)">Rename</span> </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: *"I hope to get the filename when I click Download **or Rename label**"*

Comment: yes it is obvious that he can use the same code for both.what i gave was an example of what can be done not the exact code which can be copied and pasted

Comment: No, the OP can not *use the same code for both*  because [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)
 will *"Get the **immediately preceding sibling** of each element in the set of matched elements"* That will not work for the "rename" button and is why I downvoted and left that comment

Comment: yeah i have edited it getting the prev.prev of the rename span tag

Answer (score 0):

using jquery and the data attribute is the cleanest way.

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li data-download="somefile1.txt">
      <button class="download_link">Download</button> | <button class="rename">Rename</button>
    </li>

    <li data-download="somefile2.txt">
      <button class="download_link">Download</button> | <button class="rename">Rename</button>
    </li>

    <li data-download="somefile3.txt">
      <button class="download_link">Download</button> | <button class="rename">Rename</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.download_link').click(function(){
    filename = $(this).parent().data('download');
    alert(filename);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p2wo1b5k/

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to have your events binding inline. Best practice would be to keep the code separate and clean. I would recommend using Jquery `.on()` to bind events to your elements. This will make your maintenance easy.

[A article on why inline Javascript is bad](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

After you bind the `click` event the `$(this)` will point to the element that triggered the event. Now use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/#siblings-selector) to get the value of the respective `input` element.

```js
$(function(){    // short hand for $(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').on('click',function(){
    var fileName = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    alert(fileName);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="file1" /> <span>Download</span>  <span>Rename</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="file2" /> <span>Download</span>  <span>Rename</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="file3" /> <span>Download</span>  <span>Rename</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit:** Other (optional) Couple of changes I would recommend is

- Use [data-*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) atrributes to save any information that you have to use later in jquery.
- Add the functionality of each span into its `data` attribute so that we can toggle the logic between download and rename.

```js
$(function(){
  $('span').on('click',function(){
    var fileName = $(this).closest('li').data('filename');
    debugger;
    var functionType = $(this).data('function');
    
    alert('I need to "'+functionType + '" the file '+ fileName);
    // have a if else to toggle your logic.
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-filename="file1">
    <span data-function="download">Download</span> 
    <span data-function="rename">Rename</span>
  </li>
  <li data-filename="file2">
    <span data-function="download">Download</span> 
    <span data-function="rename">Rename</span>
  </li>
  <li data-filename="file3">
    <span data-function="download">Download</span>
    <span data-function="rename">Rename</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find hidden value like below snippet. I hope this snippet will help you.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li span', function(){
 var getText = $(this).text();
 var getHiddenValue = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
 alert(getText+' : '+getHiddenValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
   <input type="hidden" value="file1">
   <span>Download</span> | <span>Rename</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="hidden" value="file2">
   <span>Download</span> | <span>Rename</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="hidden" value="file3">
   <span>Download</span> | <span>Rename</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```